# Can't run a custom IDialog in a Chain

Tags: c#, botframework

I have this IDialog

```
[Serializable]
public class SimpleDialog : IDialog
{
    public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {
        context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
    }

    private async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> argument)
    {
        IMessageActivity message = await argument;
        int length = (message.Text ?? string.Empty).Length;

        await context.PostAsync($"You sent **{message.Text}** which was **{length}** characters");
        context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
    }
}
```

It works well.
Now I try to chain it in a code like this:

```
  public static readonly IDialog MyDialog = Chain
        .PostToChain()
     .Select(_ => "Hello, quel est votre nom?")
     .PostToUser()
     .WaitToBot()
        .ContinueWith(_ => new SimpleDialog())
        .PostToUser();
```

But this doesn't compile on ContinueWith. I get the error:

*The type arguments for method 'Chain.ContinueWith(IDialog, Chain.Continuation)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.*

I tried several things but none of them are working.

What can I do to chain my dialog?

Comment: Try writing < just after .ContinueWith and it should tell you what type you have to specify

Comment: this is what I tried, but I get this error message: _Delegate 'Chain.Continuation<string, object>' does not take 1 arguments_.

I add a second argument and then: _No overload for method 'ContinueWith' takes 2 arguments_